# Eventbrite giving response " wrong datetime format" on hitting event/ endpoint

Tags: api, datetime, eventbrite

I am writing a script in python to create an event.Newbie at this.Below is the entire script code for reference.

```
        import requests,json
        from datetime import datetime

        event={}
        event['name']={}
        print("Enter the following:\ntitle of event")
        event['name']['html']=input()
        event['description']={}
        event['description']['html']=input("Event description:\n")
        event['start']={}
        startdate=datetime.strptime(input("start datetime eg :Jun 1 2005  1:33PM :\n"),'%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
        event['start']['utc']=str(startdate.date())+'T'+str(startdate.time())+'Z'
        #event['start']['utc']=startdate.isoformat()+"Z"
         #Turning datetime in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ format
        event['start']['timezone']=input("timezone eg Asia/kolkata\n")
        event['end']={}
        enddate=datetime.strptime(input("end datetime eg :Jun 1 2005  1:33PM\n"),'%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
        event['end']['utc']=str(enddate.date())+'T'+str(enddate.time())+'Z'
        #event['end']['utc']=enddate.isoformat()+"Z"
        event['end']['timezone']=event['start']['timezone']
        event['currency']=input("3 letter code")
        response = requests.post("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/",
            headers = {
                "Authorization": "Bearer NC.....",
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            data=json.dumps({"event":event}),
            verify = True,  # Verify SSL certificate
        )
```

Strictly followed the docs https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/

According to docs datatype of event.start.utc and event.start.end data shall be datetime i.e "2010-01-31T13:00:00Z"

We can see in the comments I also tried with isoformat function.

On printing event object I found the same format as specified in the docs.
But receiving response.content as  event.start invalid argument or event.start.utc as datetime wrong format use instead "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ" !!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into date issues with Eventbrite too; after debugging found this to work for events:

```
{ event:
   { name: { html: 'Postman API Event!' },
     description:
      { html: 'My fav event is The Winter Formal.' },
     start: { timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', utc: '2018-09-06T00:19:53Z' },
     currency: 'USD',
     listed: false,
     end: { timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', utc: '2018-09-06T00:20:53Z' } } }
```

and of course, different date formats in another part of API ;-)

Regarding discounts / cross event discount, where the docs specify a

> Naive Local ISO8601 date and time format

First I've heard of the 'Naive' format? Why no example Eventbrite? Here's what worked:

```
2018-10-11T12:13:14
```